# MS Access Query with CASE statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, case

I just want to get the value of one table "b" if table "a" value is "-"
If the value at table "b" is empty then get the value of table "a" even if it's "-"

Microsoft Access says "Missing operator" with this query:

```
       SELECT   ts.data_generacio, 
        ts.estat, 
        ts.exercici, 
        Month(tsl.data) AS Mes, 
        Day(tsl.data)   AS Dia, 
        tsl.data, 
        tsl.cod_treb, 
        t.nom_treb, 
        tsl.hores, 
        p.cod_proj, 
        p.acronim       AS nom_proj,
        j.justificacio, 
        tsl.timesheet_id, 
        p.ref,
        CASE WHEN tsl.activitat != '' THEN tsl.activitat ELSE ts.activitat END AS Activitat 
FROM    timesheet_lines AS tsl 
        LEFT JOIN timesheets      AS ts 
        ON tsl.timesheet_id = ts.id 
            LEFT JOIN treballadors AS t 
            ON tsl.cod_treb = t.cod_treb 
                LEFT JOIN justificacions AS 
                ON ts.id_justificacio = j.id 
                    LEFT JOIN projectes AS p 
                    ON j.cod_proj = p.cod_proj;
```

I think the error is on the CASE expression line.

Comment: That's a case _expression_, not statement...

Comment: Remove one line at the time, to find when the error disappears.

Comment: Didn't help....

Comment: So you couldn't find the error line?!?

Comment: The error line is at the Case expression line.

Comment: The edit your question and remove all unrelated rows! Keep the smallest possible complete query still having the problem.

Comment: I edit it but leaving the rest of code, I think it may be useful.

Comment: When you say `Access says "Missing operator"`... do you mean Microsoft Access? If so, Access does not support `CASE WHEN` statements on its SQL... you need to use `IIF`

Comment: Yes it is Microsoft Access

Comment: Look at my answer then, MS Access does not support `CASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access does not support `CASE` statements. Use `IIF`:

```
IIF(tsl.activitat <> '', tsl.activitat, ts.activitat ) AS Activitat
```

I'm not sure if Access supports aliases on `LEFT JOIN` either, but it probably does

Note (although correctly tagged), the title of your question might be troublesome... most people refer to Transact-SQL (TSQL) when writing "MS SQL". Transact-SQL is used by MS SQL Server, but not by MS Access, which uses its own SQL dialect (called "Access SQL", and pretty limited in comparison)