# Display column which contains dynamic values based upon values in other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: PROJECT_SELECTED and COMPANY

What I want to do is create a query which displays all COMPANIES along with a column that identifies whether or not that COMPANY has been selected for a project (which is in PROJECT_SELECTED) based upon a variable.

COMPANY

| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company1 |
| 2 | Company2 |
| 3 | Company3 |

PROJECT_SELECTED

This table shows whether a certain company has been selected for a specific project.

| PROJECT_ID | COMPANY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

This is the output that I want

Variable: PROJECT_ID = 1

| COMPANY_ID | PROJECT_TENDERED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | True |
| 3 | False |

The SQL I wrote out goes something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN COMPANY_ID EXISTS IN 
          (SELECT COMPANY_ID FROM PROJECT_SELECTED WHERE PROJECT_ID=1) THEN "TRUE"
       ELSE "FALSE"
       END AS PROJECT_TENDERED
FROM COMPANY;
```

The variable referenced above this table is what I will be using to determine which project I am referencing. I am not worried about the changing of variable as the program I am using (Microsoft Access/VBA) has a requery functionality.

Simply put, how do I make a column that does not exist in either table which defaults to no but yes if it is found in PROJECT_SELECTED. The important part is that I can see **all** companies.

Comment: Would someone mind helping me out with the table formatting? It looks good in the editing stage but messes up when posted. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If i get your task right you don't need to create a column - you need to write a good query. You should use CASE statement or  COALESCE or smth else. Give a query example and try to do my solution in it

Comment: @letronas I updated my post, is that along the lines of the path I should be going for?

Comment: What database platform is data in? Access query does not support CASE.

Comment: Hi @June7 , thank you for that insight. Bummer that it does not, I had the whole CASE statement written out. But finally figured it out with the ```IIF```! :)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier with `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT
  company.company_name,
  IIF(project_selected.project_id IS NULL, 'False', 'True')
FROM
  company
LEFT JOIN
  project_selected
    ON  project_selected.company_id = company.company_id
    AND project_selected.project_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out at my own peril.

Seems Access does not support CASE statements. We must use `IIF` instead. In the `IIF` expression I have an inner query which determines if the COMPANY_ID is in the PROJECT_SELECTED table for a certain project. This is achieved using the WHERE statement in the inner query.

I have figured out the query based upon [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582390/ms-access-query-with-case-statement#43583571)

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME, 
IIF(COMPANY_ID IN 
   (SELECT COMPANY_ID FROM PROJECT_SELECTED WHERE PROJECT_ID = 1),'TRUE','FALSE')
AS PROJECT_TENDERED
FROM COMPANY;
```